Traversing linked list in raylib gives Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I am trying to DrawText in Raylib Application.When I traverse Linklist in which content is either application prints nothing or gives Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Case No 1 : Segmentation fault (core dumped)
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char *name;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node *first = NULL;

void create(char *array[] ,int n){
    struct Node *node , *last;
    first = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->name = array[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last = first;

    for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){
        node  = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        node->name = array[i];
        node->next = NULL;
        last->next = node;
        last = node;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char *array[] = {"First","Second","third"};
    InitWindow(800,600,"Test");
    SetTargetFPS(60);
    create(array, 3);
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(DARKGRAY);
        int pos = 20;
        while (70 > pos) {
            DrawText(first->name, 20, pos, 14 ,WHITE);
            pos = pos + 20;
            first = first->next;
        }
        EndDrawing();
    }
    return 0;
}

This code prints text but application crash and gives Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Case 2 : Prints nothing
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char *name;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node *first = NULL;

void create(char *array[] ,int n){
    struct Node *node , *last;
    first = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->name = array[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last = first;

    for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){
        node  = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        node->name = array[i];
        node->next = NULL;
        last->next = node;
        last = node;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char *array[] = {"First","Second","third"};
    InitWindow(800,600,"Test");
    SetTargetFPS(60);
    create(array, 3);
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(DARKGRAY);
        int pos = 20;
        while (first) {
            DrawText(first->name, 20, pos, 14 ,WHITE);
            pos = pos + 20;
            first = first->next;
        }
        EndDrawing();
    }
    return 0;
}

This prints nothing but app donot crash.
I am try to print element data of linklist. If anyone can please let me know what I am doing wrong

I don't know Raylib, but...
In the first case it's obvious that you're doing a second pass through the while (!WindowShouldClose()) without resetting the first pointer. The three iterations of the internal while (first) are solved well, but then you just point to nothing (first->next has become NULL), and the line DrawText(first->name, 20, pos, 14 ,WHITE);, at the beginning of the second pass of the external loop, triggers the segmentation fault.
In any case, you shouldn't advance the pointer (first = first->next) without previously testing that first->next != NULL. Or, if you accept a NULL in the pointer (your choice), you should verify that first != NULL before accessing first->name or first->next.
Edit: your approach is better in the second case, because you avoid dereferencing a NULL pointer. The inner loop is only executed one (it DO print the three names!), and the external loop keeps on forever.

My approach is second one but it does not draw text. If I print first->name on standard out it prints it. I think its a raylib thing that it does not print in loop but why do it print in first condition.

Well... Then you're facing two different problems. Take my advice and first test your list traversal code without using the Raylib functions. I did it and each version behave as I said. When you got that right, investigate the other problem. As I said, I don't know Raylib but you're clearing the background (actually erasing the previously written words) at the beginning of EACH cycle of the external loop.
